# Create (Cmake) C/C++ Library to Android without Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My goal is create a external library made in C/C++ which I can import in my Android Project.

I know how to **import**, I know how to **create** a library from C/C++ **inside** the project using JNI, Cmake, etc. But this is not my goal.

For this I'm using small steps, first with a simple library:

**gmath.c**

```
#include "gmath.h"

#if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 4
#define GMATH_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#elif defined(__SUNPRO_C) && (__SUNPRO_C >= 0x590)
#define GMATH_EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#else
#define GMATH_EXPORT
#endif

GMATH_EXPORT unsigned gpower(unsigned n) {
    return 44;
}
```

**gmath.h**

```
#ifndef __POWER_HPP__
#define __POWER_HPP__
/*
 * return pow(2, n)
*/
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif // __cplusplus
       unsigned gpower(unsigned n);

#endif //__POWER_HPP__
```

What I'm using the create the library:
`cmake 
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=
/Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/android.toolchain.cmake 
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=
/Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ -DANDROID_ABI="arm64-v8a"`

**CMake**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/android.toolchain.cmake")
set(ANDROID_NDK "/Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/")

add_library(gmath STATIC src/gmath.c)

set(distribution_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../../distribution")
set_target_properties(gmath
                  PROPERTIES
                  ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
                  "${distribution_DIR}/gmath/lib/${ANDROID_ABI}")
```

The problem is, when I use the `lipo -info libgmath.a`by terminal it show a different ABI:

[image]

**How can I build this external library to android using the rights parameters?**

Comment: During `cmake ...` invocation it should be output about toolchain is used, which compiler is used and so on. Is that output corresponds to the Android? You may add that output to the question post, so we can check it. BTW, in `CMakeLists.txt` it is very recommended to use `project(...)` call. While CMake may perform such call automatically, it may miss some specifics. Hint: If you want specify output directory for all static libraries, you may set `CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable instead of setting the property `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use cmake toolchain from ndk, not sdk:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE= /Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM= /Users/vcanato/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ -DANDROID_ABI="arm64-v8a"
```

Comment: Instead of a huge command-line, see **step 1** of [how to set Android tool-chain in cmake-script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67729248/8740349) (tested with latest Android-Studio and v3.1, but the `ANDROID_ABI` option is unavoidable)